# How can we create a adapter with NTML authentication

Tags: worklight-adapters, worklight-server

How can we call web service from JAVA adapter with NTML authentication?

Answer (score 0):

For all practical purposes, a Java adapter can be treated as any other Java project.

Which means, there isn't anything specific to IBM MobileFirst that you need to call a backend utilising NTLM authentication.

Apache HttpClient supports NTLM authentication while calling endpoints.

I found these examples:

[Chapter 4. HTTP authentication](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)

[Http Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html)

You should find many other working Java samples online. Once you have understood, you should be able to write something similar into the Java adapter project - which is in turn a JAX-RS project.

For adding dependencies and building a Java adapter , refer to this link:

[Creating Java and JavaScript Adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/)